# How to implement joystick rotation in BGE?

Tags: game-engine

I haven't been able to find an answer to this question anywhere. I want to have my character face in the direction the analog stick is pointed. How can I do this?

Comment: which address is the one pointed by the stick ???

Comment: If you have an XBox 360 gamepad then try this game I made for your question (it was made using windows 7 64bit blender 2.66a). Texture images might not be loaded though- but gameplay will still work. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6476" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6476/)

Answer (score 0):

How about give an empty a joystick sensor to drive a message actuator with an appropriate subject, then give your character a message sensor to pick up the message and drive a motion actuator?